# is it possible to move a list type inside a div css

Tags: html, css

is there a way to move this list type inside the div. right now it only way stay in the margin or outside the div.

i have tried to look around but couldn't find anything

[How i would like it to move](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HHhN.png)

i hope everything is there:)

css

```css
  @import url(https://allfont.net/allfont.css?fonts=star-jedi);

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    font-family: 'Star Jedi', arial;
    color: #34a9d1;
    font-size: 8px;

    background-image: url(https://mcdn.wallpapersafari.com/medium/71/62/rKOEyo.jpg);
}
.con {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}
.box {
    border: 3px solid rgba(52, 169, 209, 0.8);
    background-color: rgba(2, 31, 48, 0.8);
    
    height: 70vh;
    width: 600px;
    margin: auto;

    align-items: center;
}
.list{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
.info{
    display: list-item;
    list-style-type: circle;
    width: 90%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(52, 169, 209, 0.4);
    margin:  auto ;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
   
    <div class="con">
        <div class="box">
            <div class="list">
                <div class="info name">Name</div>
                <div class="info height">Height</div>
                <div class="info mass">Mass</div>
                <div class="info hairColor">Hair color</div>
                <div class="info skinColor">Skin color</div>                    
                <div class="info eyeColor">Eye color</div>
                <div class="info birthYear">Birth Year</div>
                <div  class="info gender">Gender</div>
                <div class="info homeworld">Homeworld</div>
            </div>
            <div class="btn">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[i wanna move it in here inside the div but it keeps being outside in the margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmquY.png)

Comment: Your `box` isn't tall enough.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works but only if the viewport is big enough to contain the height of the whole list.

Two options:

- Remove height:70vh; from .box
- If you want to keep the height:70vh; add overflow-x:hidden to .box
  That way, if the box is smaller than the size of the list, it's scrollable

If you want space between the border of your box and the list, adjust the padding by .list